# Rebus: Shanghai

Tags: rebus

I didn't write this rebus but I like it so I'm sharing it.

Image form:

[image: Image form of Rebus]

Text form:

```
   J   K 
10   Q   A
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

i think its

> hijacking - jack-king are higher than the other face cards symbols.

Comment: Gamow corrected me and gave you the win.

Answer (score 15):

As shanghaiing is kidnapping people to serve as sailors, the title "Shanghai" suggests:

> "A high Jack and King" = **"hijacking"**

Comment: You beat Bozman by less than a minute.

Comment: @EngineerToast Bozman actually answered 19 seconds earlier... Mouse over the time stamp and it will give you the exact time.

Comment: @mdc32 I had no idea you could do that. I tried going to your profiles to see the answer time and it gave yours as 31 minutes ago and Bozman's as 32 minutes ago. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @EngineerToast I'm not Gamow, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: You get my upvote for also tying it in to the title.

Answer (score 1):

I see this has already been answered. But I thought it was

> a house of cards

due to the layout.  Although

> it's not finished yet, it still needs a third layer!

Answer (score 1):

I can expand the answer of the rebus like this :

> Hijacking 10 Q A (Hijacking 10 question and answer sites)